# Не могу получить ответ от сервера на GET запрос через cURL php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

У меня есть node сервер который принимает GET запросы и возвращает ответ (Тестил через браузер, Постмен , консоль curl - всё работает)

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const webpush = require('web-push');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/' ,(req,res) => {
console.log('-------------- GET --------------')
res.status(201).send('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><title>Document</title></head><body>hi</body></html>')
})
```

И есть страничка php через которую я отправляю запрос (так же тестил на других ссылках - всё работает )

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $output;
 curl_close($ch);
```

Но при попытке отправить запрос с этой странички на сервер - выдаёт 524 ошибку , подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524991/php-curl-not-executing-error-524-timeout

Comment: Yes, really the mistake was in this, thank you very much )

Answer (score 0):

Обратился к хост провайдеру ,чтобы он открыл порт на котором я запускаю сервер - ошибка пропала , спасибо за подсказку )